# Change the styling of function arguments in VS Code

Tags: arguments, styling, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to edit the styling in my Visual Studio Code workspace and I don't know how to edit the styling of function arguments. I have found that you can style *parameters* (using textMateRules and `"scope" = "variable.parameter"`) but can't find anything on styling *arguments* (when calling the function as opposed to defining it.)

Hopefully someone could find me the textMateRules scope name or some other way of getting at it in VS Code settings. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found: It is possible to inspect scopes using `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` in the Command Palette. I was able to find the setting which was `meta.function-call.arguments.python`